# Managing a development codebase in Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm moving to serverless with AWS Lambda. I've gotten to "hello world" so far. I'm used to having a development codebase that I work on, test, and then promote to production.  Is there an easy way to do this with Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use different AWS accounts for `dev`, `staging`, and `prod`. When deploying the Lambda, I just choose which AWS profile to use so it deploys to the right environment.

If you're using a single AWS account, each deployment of a Lambda function will have a version. You can use those.

[image]

If you're using API Gateway with Lambda, you can use API Gateway's "Stages".

[image]

You should use a deployment framework such as [serverless](https://serverless.com/framework/) and that will make things easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using frameworks like serverless makes it easy to develop, configure and deploy lambdas, API gateways and other events to AWS. I highly recommend that you adapt serverless framework. This makes it easier to integrate and use serveless deployment with your current CI system.

Now if you have all your environments within one AWS account then you can use stages to represent each env. Using serverless you can simply deploy the lambdas to a different env using --stage (-s) argument.

```
serverless deploy -s <env/stage name>
```

You put some smarts in configuring serverless yaml file to pick up configuration files based on your stage (assuming that you will require accessing diff resources like db, s3 buckets etc for diff environments)

If you are using different AWS accounts for prod and nonprod (recommended) then all you need to do is provide an additional argument for the profile.

```
serverless deploy --profile <prod/nonprod profile> --stage <prod/nonprod stage>
```

Comment: Also, Serverless has a variety of plugins that enable offline development and testing.